# Actionscript specify relevant events in MXML?

Tags: apache-flex, events, actionscript, mxml, event-handling

When I add something like a button to my code, I can enter something like this:

```
<mx:Button id="myButton"
```

When I click space, I get the public properties, methods, etc, as well as all the relevant events, such as "Click". I can type click, and have it auto-generate a method stub to handle those kinds of events.

My question is, how do I specify the relevant events, and specify what the method stubs look like? I'm having a hard time finding this since I'm not quite sure what search terms to use. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a little confused here. Are you trying to create auto-complete suggestions for your own custom events?

Comment: @Jason Towne: Yes, basically. I was hoping to have something like `<custom:MyControl id="test" someEvent="specify handler here" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the [Event metadata tag](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf680e1-7ffe.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a24) in your component to control that behavior.

For example, if you wanted to use `Event.CHANGE`, you would add the following metadata tag to the class:

```
[Event name="change",type="flash.events.Event")]
```